# OnSwipe is not detected by MotionLayout being a ViewPager the anchorId

Tags: android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-viewpager2, android-motionlayout

My parent view is a Motion Layout. In it I have a ViewPager which has 2 pages. Each page has a vertical recycler view.

My desired effect is for a textView, which is a child of this motion layout, to change its color on page swipe (and to do it smoothly).

**PROBLEM:** Nothing happens on swipe. Just a regular ViewPager swipe

Here is my transition:

```
    <Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/start">
    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
        app:touchAnchorSide="right"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/news_viewPager"/>
    </Transition>
```

I've set a listener on the Motion Layout `motionlayout.addTransitionListener()` and I'm debugging in its four methods (such as onTransitionChange()) to see if the animation is set off, but it doesn't even starts.

I've tried adding `touchRegionId`, `disableScroll` & `disablePostScroll` but I'm out of ideas.

Could someone please explain to me **why** it is not working, and a solution to it (or at least an alternative)? Thank you.

Just in case, here's my full scene xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/new_videos_title">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="@color/navBarOn" />
    </Constraint>

    <Constraint android:id="@id/news_viewPager" />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/new_articles_title">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="@color/navBarOff" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/news_viewPager" />

    <Constraint android:id="@id/new_videos_title">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="@color/navBarOff" />
    </Constraint>

    <Constraint android:id="@id/new_articles_title">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textColor"
            app:customColorValue="@color/navBarOn" />
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/start">
    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
        app:touchAnchorSide="right"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/news_viewPager"/>
</Transition>
```

Comment: Please share the xml of the layout. Also, try to add a layout that contains the view pager as a child and the touchAnchorId on the parent layout.